# Efficiently count all the divisors of a number in c++

Tags: c++

I need to find the number of the divisors of a fibonacci number.

I tried this, but it's not efficient enough:

```
int nrdiv(int val) {
    int n = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= val / 2; i++){
        if (val % i == 0){
            n++;
        }
    }
    return n+1;
}
```

For example, for the 21 number it should return 4 and for 124 it should return 6.

I'd love to find a better way to count them. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for sharing your homework. I frankly can't think of a faster way to do this.

Comment: Do it to the square root of `n` and multiply by 2? You will need to account for perfect squares of course.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think there are some optimizations you can do based on the assumption that the number is a Fibonacci number.

Answer (score -1):

Just for clarification, do you need the number of **distinct** divisors or just the number of divisors?

A quick and easy optimization will be to iterate until sqrt(n) instead of n/2.

if you are reffering to the not distinct version you could implement a recursive function with this sudo-code:

```
nrdiv(N):
if N = 1 return 1

iterate with i from 1 to sqrt(N):

    if(i divides N) return 1+nrdiv(N/i)

return 1
```

the last line of the psudo code is used for handling prime numbers.

don't how much better this is in terms of efficiency but this is much cleaner
Good luck!

Comment: For example, for the 21 number it should return 4 and for 124 it should return 6.